# Cannot access k8s service from amazon linux 2 minikube cluster

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ec2, minikube

I am running a minikube cluster (driver docker) on amazon linux 2. I have a pod and service created. I'm having issues accessing the service from my browser

```
#pod.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: webapp
  labels:
    app: webapp
spec:
  containers:
  - name: webapp
    image: richardchesterwood/k8s-fleetman-webapp-angular:release0
```

```
#service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: fleetman-webapp

spec:
  selector:
    app: webapp

  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      nodePort: 30080

  type: NodePort
```

When i try and hit the public ip and node port in the browser, it times out. What am i missing here?

Comment: Are you allowing port 30080 in your security group? Your pod spec is missing a defined containerPort. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/

Comment: Did this and it made no difference